# SSRS Create Link to URL

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I am hosting a SSRS report through the SSRS Report Viewer Control inside a ASP.NET web form.  For the action property on a text box I am setting the following expression.

```
=Parameters!URL.Value & "?customerid=" & Fields!CustomerID.Value
```

The desired result is something like this.

> URL = “http://www.google.com/somesamplepage.aspx?customerid=26074C16-BFA2-4610-8D3F-9EF550FE77D1”

The problem is that the Fields!CustomerID value is a Guid datatype.  SSRS does not display the hyperlink for me in this scenario.  However, if I update the querystring with another text value from the fields collection it works fine.

Any ideas out there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried

```
=Parameters!URL.Value & "?customerid=" & Fields!CustomerID.Value.ToString()
```

Comment: hey I am editing my answer from Fields!CustomerID.ToString() to Fields!CustomerID.Value.ToString(). even though eariler answer worked.. Fields!CustomerID.Value.ToString() is more accurate.

Comment: @everyone: Be careful, if it's a GUID, you might have to do ToString().ToLowerInvariant() or it won't work correctly.